# rsync a folder ignoring sud-dirs which has with circular symlink

Tags: linux, rsync, symbolic-link

I am trying to rsync a folder as below:

```
rsync -ahLz ./src /tmp/
```

Dir "./src" has circulr symlink as:

```
$ ls -l src/cpp/blddir
lrwxrwxrwx 1 lnxbuild users 16 May 27 02:16 src/cpp/blddir -> ../../../1.36.02
```

rsync fails as it has circular symlink:

```
rsync: readlink_stat("<root of the dir>/src/blddir/lib/abyss/src/blddir/lib/abyss/src/blddir/lib/abyss/src/blddir/lib/abyss/src/blddir/lib/abyss/src/blddir/lib/abyss/src/blddir/lib/abyss/src/blddir/lib/abyss/src/blddir/lib/abyss/src/blddir/lib/abyss/src/blddir/lib/abyss/src/blddir/lib/abyss/src/blddir/lib/abyss/src/blddir/lib/abyss/src/blddir/lib/abyss/src/blddir/lib/abyss/src/blddir/lib/abyss/src/blddir/lib/abyss/src/blddir/lib/abyss/src/blddir/lib/abyss/src/blddir/lib/abyss/src/blddir/lib/abyss/src/blddir/lib/abyss/src/blddir/lib/abyss/src/blddir/lib/abyss/src/blddir/lib/abyss/src/blddir/lib/abyss/src/blddir/lib/abyss/src/blddir/lib/abyss/src/blddir/lib/abyss/src/blddir/lib/abyss/src/blddir/lib/abyss/src/blddir/lib/abyss/src/blddir/lib/abyss/src/blddir/lib/abyss/src/blddir/lib/abyss/src/blddir/lib/abyss/src/blddir/lib/abyss/src/blddir/lib/libutil/libxmlrpc_util.so") failed: Too many levels of symbolic links (40)
```

is there an option to "rsync all folders and files, but ignore rsync'ing the directories/files inside which has circular link"? right now I am using option *--exclude-from=file-with-list-of-dirs-with-circular-link.txt*, but the list keeps growing and I had to maintain the exclude list file which I want to avoid.

Comment: Is there some reason you don't want to recreate the symlinks (the -L option)? I don't think you'd have the problem if you omitted the -L and used -l to create the symlinks in the receiving tree.

Comment: thanks, but we don't want to have any circular symlink in receiving tree, because some automation process rsync's that folder to some other place later and that will fail, and I have no permission to update that automation script.